# counting of references of an object

Tags: c++

I'm feeling confusion that is there any way to count the reference of an object of the class?

```
class A
{
  public :
    A(){}
}

int main()
{
  A obj;
  A * ptr1 = &obj;
  A * ptr2 = &obj;
  A * ptr3 = &obj; 
}
```

now how i'll be able to know that my object **obj** is referenced by three pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Raw pointers do not do reference-counting. You would need to either implement a reference-counting smart pointer class yourself, or use an already existing one, such as [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

`shared_ptr` allows you to access its reference count with the `use_count()` member function.

For example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public :
    A(){}
}

int main()
{
  //Dynamically allocate an A rather than stack-allocate it, as shared_ptr will
  //try to delete its object when the ref count is 0.
  std::shared_ptr<A> ptr1(new A());
  std::shared_ptr<A> ptr2(ptr1);
  std::shared_ptr<A> ptr3(ptr1);
  std::cout<<"Count: "<<ptr1.use_count()<<std::endl; //Count: 3
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only if you implement it yourself. If you come from a C# or Java (or other managed language) then this can be a difficult concept.

You would be better using one of the standard pointer types provided by [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

For example, [`shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) will keep a count of all the 'references' to your objects and manage the lifecycle. [`unique_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will only allow a single pointer to your object.